# Exporting Textures for .obj file for Element 3D

Tags: texturing

I'm new to blender.  I just modeled this shotgun shell and I want to use it for video purposes.  When I save it as an .obj file it comes with a .mtl file that Element 3D in After Effects doesn't recognize.  So when I upload it into Element 3D, the model is there but doesn't have any texture or color.  I "smart UV Unwrapped" each of the 4 parts of the shell.  Is there any way to get an image file of the entire shell that I can upload in Element 3D to make the shell look the way it does in the render view of Blender?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Answer (score -1):

You need to bake your textures in order to use it inside Element 3D as diffuse, Normal and so.
Here is one tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut-KYKbnj8A&t=434s

Good Luck
pixldgblog.com