# Export a 3D model with texture , into element 3D

Tags: export

Is there any solution to import a 3d model with its texture, into element 3d?

I'm using blender 2.8, and I will appreciate if you mention any reference wich describe that, using 2.8 version

Thank you very much

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131069/exporting-textures-for-obj-file-for-element-3d/131071#131071